# smarter "reverse" of a dictionary in python (acc for some of values being the same)?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def revert_dict(d):
    rd = {}
    for key in d:
        val = d[key]
        if val in rd:
            rd[val].append(key)
        else:
            rd[val] = [key]
    return rd

>>> revert_dict({'srvc3': '1', 'srvc2': '1', 'srvc1': '2'}) 
{'1': ['srvc3', 'srvc2'], '2': ['srvc1']}
```

This obviously isn't simple exchange of keys with values: this would overwrite some values (as new keys) which is NOT what I'm after.

If 2 or more values are the same for different keys, keys are supposed to be grouped in a list.

The above function works, but I wonder if there is a smarter / faster way?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Python, but maybe there's something you could do with `setdefault()` on the dict, to collapse the 4 lines of the if-statement into 1?

Comment: can we assume that values of initial dictionary are immutable (qualify as keys), or could it be list of such ? In other words do you want the function to be inversible ? I guess not, as yours isn't, but it could also be a bug in the current implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks pretty good. You could simplify it a little bit by using [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import collections

def revert_dict(d):
    rd = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        rd[value].append(key)

    return rd
```

Comment: +1 I was going to post something nearly identical. Note that this isn't necessarily faster (as in, raw time spent doing it) but has the same time and space complexity and any actual difference will be negible.

Comment: +1. I just posted an almost identical answer, then deleted it :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach. Not sure if this is faster (I doubt that).

```
from itertools import groupby

old_dict = {'srvc3': '1', 'srvc2': '1', 'srvc1': '2'}
funcval = d.__getitem__
new_dict = dict((val, list(keys)) for val, keys in \
                groupby(sorted(d.iterkeys(), key=funcval), funcval))

# new_dict:
# {'1': ['srvc3', 'srvc2'], '2': ['srvc1']}
```

Your initial code is certainly not bad (readable) although I would probably have written it like this (mostly personal preference, really):

```
def revert_dict(d):
    rd = {}
    for key, val in d.items():
        try:
            rd[val].append(key)
        except KeyError:
            rd[val] = [key]
    return rd
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not as efficient, but:

```
ks, vs = old_dict.items()
new_dict = dict((v, [k for k in ks if old_dict[k] == v]) for v in set(vs))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def invertDictionary(d):
    rd = {}
    for x,y in d.iteritems():
            if y in rd.keys():
                  rd[y].append(x)
            else:
                  rd[y] = [x]
    return rd
```

I find this most readable to myself. Any downsides?

Answer (score 0):

```
def revert_dict(d):
    rd = {}
    for key,val in d.iteritems():
        rd[val] = rd.get(val,[]) + [key]
    return rd


print revert_dict({'srvc3': '1', 'srvc2': '1', 'srvc1': '2',
             'srvc4': '8', 'srvc5': '2', 'srvc6': '2',
             'srvc7': '77', 'srvc8': '1', 'srvc9': '2',
             'srvc10': '3', 'srvc11': '1'})
```

result

```
{'1': ['srvc11', 'srvc3', 'srvc2', 'srvc8'], '77': ['srvc7'], '3': ['srvc10'], '2': ['srvc6', 'srvc5', 'srvc1', 'srvc9'], '8': ['srvc4']}
```

also:

```
def revert_dict(d):
    rd = {}
    for key,val in d.iteritems():
        rd[val] = rd[val]+ [key] if val in rd else  [key]
    return rd
```